# Varnish module for Boxen (for OSX)

Tags: varnish, boxen

Is there a varnish module for Boxen? Similar to this one https://github.com/maxchk/puppet-varnish but tested on OSX

Currently none is listed in Github's Boxen org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install varnish with brew, so it should be as adding this to your `site.pp` in your `our-boxen` repo:

```
package {
    [
      'varnish',
    ]:
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull a certain puppet from GitHub repo like puppet-varnish and put it in your `Puppetfile` like this one:

```
github "varnish",         "x.x.x", repo => "maxchk/puppet-varnish"
github "python",          "2.0.1"
github "postgresql",      "4.0.1"
```

And call it by putting a code inside your `site.pp`:

```
include varnish
```

That's it, run the Boxen again and it should install your desired puppet.
Although this question is old, I've answered it for reference.